# How can I tail a file and capture the output for one minute?

Tags: tail

I am tailing a log file. How can I capture the output for one minute?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
tail -f mylogfile & sleep 60; kill $!
```

Answer (score 0):

You fail to mention your OS, Shell or other pertinent infos.  Therefore, I recommend entering your command and watching the clock for one minute, then sending the 'break' command.

The Cron command springs to mind to schedule tasks assuming you are running an Linux/UNIX box.